# Save qemu VM state like in Virtualbox

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, qemu

I am used to the Virtualbox "save machine state" exit strategy, which is a handy way to let the host reboot without shutting down the vm.

I recently switched to qemu because of its VT-x in VT-x support, necessary for VS2015 emulators, and missing in Virtualbox.

I can handle the commandline startup, but what I haven't been able to do succesfully is to save a VM's state that can be later booted up and resumed. How can I do this? Note that libvirt's virtual machine manager is not an option as I can't seem to install the networking firewall dependencies (nor does it seem necessary, so I don't really want to). I'm running Arch Linux.

Comment: Just to clarify something. I use VirtualBox myself, and VT-x support is there. You just have to enable it per machine and install the guest addons to use it. Also, it will be disabled if you have another VM installed and its drivers are loaded first. Also, only available on x64 installs.

Comment: @LPChip what I mean is that the guest OS cannot access the VT-x capabilities. Qemu (and VMWare for that matter) have a pass-through mechanism. See [this Virtualbox bug report](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032).

Comment: Ah, my bad. I thought you meant that VT-x was not detected even. Just wanted to make sure you were aware VT-x is there. but you appear to be a step ahead even. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the "savevm" and "loadvm" command in the qemu monitor. The entire state of the machine is saved, exactly as in virtualbox. The only caveat is that the drive image file has to be in qcow2 format. You can find out more about qemu monitor from the following site:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Monitor#savevm

Comment: I think it's worth to mention that qcow2 can be easily converted to any other format if you ever need it.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers I will also add my current solution.

If you set up your VM through libvirt (e.g. through virt-manager) then virt-manager provides a functional UI to handle your VM's execution states, including a save state which then automatically resumes as well.

I highly recommend anyone going the Qemu route to use the libvirt machinery. It provides a small layer of usability (and also of extra UI complexity) that makes the day to day usage so much more pleasant.