# How to work with QEMU snapshots/savevm in a way that is predictable like virtual box?

Tags: qemu

Q: is there a way to have a running QEMU vm, where i have the option to (online or offline) save a restore-point as I go?

long text with investigation, alternatives already examined and small rants:

I'm having a hard time to grasp qemu multiple, completely incompatible, ways of storing and discarding state/changes to a vm and disks.

There is the [`-snapshot`](https://wiki.qemu.org/Features/Snapshots#Live_Snapshots) flag. But it doesn't seem to be done (quote from doc

> It is a work in progress and things may change as we progress.

), and depends on [guest agent](https://wiki.qemu.org/Features/GuestAgent#Detailed_Summary), which also doesn't seem to be done and is somewhat broken as devs changed gears when migrating it from QMP to QAPI, and then scratched that halfway to work on libvirt overkill "solutions".

Both those documents mention QEMU version 0.16~17... but my systems all have version 7.2+ so i'm not sure if it is some internal lib version or really old documents.

Then there's [filesystem snapshots](https://wiki.qemu.org/Features/Snapshots#Block_Commit_.5Bproposal.2C_preliminary.5D) `-drive file=hda.qcow2,snapshot=on` which doesn't seem to work on my system. I mean, it works as everything is always trhown away when using that option. There's no way to actually commit any data to a snapshot to the QCOW2 image.

Then, there is [`savevm` monitor command](https://wiki.qemu.org/Features/SnapshottingImprovements), but while it is the only one that seems to actually make use of the QCOW2 snapshot capabilites, it will also store lots of undesirable CPU/memory state (they are more an annoyance that breaks things later on and only really help in rare QA cases, and i don't see a way to easily discard them on next run and only keep the QCOW2 changes)

And there's what I wanted. A way to always commit changes, but having a way to, when the machine is **offline** save that point in the [storage as a snapshot](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/CreateSnapshot).

But that last method is completely disconnected from qemu and the images. I have to create new file names as i progress, instead of adding save states.

I think the ideal state would be to have this offline state method, but using internal QCOW2 snapshot support instead of different files.

Finally, there's [another option](https://wiki.qemu.org/Features/Snapshots2) that is the last offline use case, but done online. i.e. while running the vm, pause execution via qemu agent, create a new snapshot file on the external host, and instruct the running instance to switch to that new snapshot overlay and resume execution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you mean by predictable, but I think you might be looking for this:

```
List, apply, create or delete snapshots in image FILENAME.

qemu-img snapshot \
    [--object OBJECTDEF] [--image-opts] [-U] [-q] \
    [-l | -a SNAPSHOT | -c SNAPSHOT | -d SNAPSHOT] FILENAME


    Parameters to snapshot subcommand:

    SNAPSHOT
           Is the name of the snapshot to create, apply or delete

    -a     Applies a snapshot (revert disk to saved state)
    -c     Creates a snapshot
    -d     Deletes a snapshot
    -l     Lists all snapshots in the given image
```

(from the qemu-img manpage & https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/tools/qemu-img.html#cmdoption-qemu-img-commands-arg-snapshot )

This command will create an *internal* snapshot / checkpoint within the qcow2 vm image (i'm not sure if it works with other disk formats).

(Unlike the format `qemu-img snapshot create -f qcow2 -b <backing.file> -F qcow2 <image.file>` which will create a new on-disk image file and use the existing one as a backing file. - Good for immutable archives.)

For the full list of features supported by your specific qemu version, check `qemu-img --help` output.

Example:

```
$ qemu-img snapshot -l myamazingqemuvm.qcow2
$ qemu-img snapshot -c testing myamazingqemuvm.qcow2
$ qemu-img snapshot -l myamazingqemuvm.qcow2
Snapshot list:
ID        TAG               VM SIZE                DATE     VM CLOCK     ICOUNT
1         testing               0 B 2023-05-21 00:57:50 00:00:00.000          0
$ qemu-img snapshot -d testing myamazingqemuvm.qcow2
$ qemu-img snapshot -l myamazingqemuvm.qcow2
$
```

To create a snapshot, `qemu-img` **requires a write lock** on the file, meaning it will only work for offline VMs.

---

To create a **snapshot** in **an online VM**, you need to use the "HMP" commands from within the running `qemu-system` process:

```
(qemu) savevm my_snapshot

(qemu) loadvm my_snapshot
```

to save and load snapshots, respectively.
To get such a console in your terminal-started VM, you might start it with the `monitor` argument:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 [...] -monitor unix:/tmp/qemu-mon_${VMNAME}.sock,server,nowait
```

which will create a unix socket to communicate with your VM:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
#
# connect to qemu monitor socket
# disconnect from it with Ctrl-C

MACHINE="${1}"
SOCKET="/tmp/qemu-mon_${MACHINE}.sock"

echo "CONNECTING TO ${MACHINE} ..."
socat ${SOCKET} STDIN
```

and then all you need to do is

```
$ ./qemu-monitor.sh myamazingqemuvm
CONNECTING TO myamazingqemuvm ...
QEMU 5.2.0 monitor - type 'help' for more information
(qemu) savevm testsnap
savevm testsnap
(qemu) loadvm testsnap
loadvm testsnap
```

... and once you're back offline, you can switch back to using `qemu-img snapshot`:

```
$ qemu-img snapshot -l myamazingqemuvm.qcow2
Snapshot list:
ID        TAG               VM SIZE                DATE     VM CLOCK     ICOUNT
1         testing               0 B 2023-05-21 00:57:50 00:00:00.000          0
2         testsnap          14.3 MiB 2023-05-21 01:03:45 00:05:32.995
```

Comment: that is the second alternative listed on the question, besides requiring pausing the emulation and several other workarounds to work, this is clearly a feature for kernel hackers and not regular users. Too much memory/cpu state is kept which prevents simply loading the state without further work.

Comment: Aight, sorry I wasted my time. If you're actually looking for an answer that meets your requirements, I would suggest cleaning up your question from the rambling bits. I don't see what in this is a "kernel hacker" feature tbh. I feel it's pretty equivalent to `VBoxManage snapshot` for my needs. There is no need to pause emulation, if you have issues with the emulation pausing for snapshotting, then I feel it might rather be you not having "regular user" needs. In any case, if you like how vbox snapshots work, just stick with it?

Comment: i will give it another try with your steps. appreciate it. but from my test it was impossible to restart it with a different host network connection, for example.

Comment: @gcb, I'll grant that I haven't tried that scenario in either virtualization solution. So you can't change qemu network options if VM has a snapshot, but it works after deleting the snapshot? Perhaps I should add that `aqemu` has a GUI for snapshots, and `virt-manager` as well (but works via `libvirt`), but I haven't really tested either.

Comment: thanks! i confess i have abandoned "official" snapshots and am simply stopping the vm, copying the image file, restarting the vm. So far it is working well and i can work around the downtime in other ways. when i do have some time i will try to debug starting from your steps.